# How to grab the titles from the list (or string) of the urls?

Tags: python-3.x

I've parsed some links from google search and now can't take titles from them. How can I do it on python 3 (mac os). I know about beautifulsoap and lxml, but I didn't manage to use them in the code..

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

keyword = input('Type keyword: ')

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?q={keyword}&num=100&hl=en')

links = r.html.xpath('//div[@class="r"]/a[1]/@href') #get the list of urls

a = links[ :11] #get 10 urls from the list

string = '\n'.join(a) #make a string from the list
```

what's next???

Comment: can you show what you want to retrieve? you have the urls, what do you want instead? if you have to analyse each page, you cannot join the list of urls. You have to loop on each url to download it and parse it

Comment: Yes, I need to analyse the urls and get titles from every URL. So I need to download them firstly and after that to parse titles from each of them?

Comment: that or get that information from the google search itself

Comment: Can you show hot to get the information from the google search? Should I use "for... in..."  and xpath all gotten urls? Or something else?